# JMeterLib Robot Framework- Pass parameters as keywords

Tags: testing, jmeter, robotframework

I have a csv file with 3 columns, I am reading the columns and creating a different list for each column I want to pass this with JmeterLib for robot framework, I want to read the list and send each value in the list a parameter for "Load testing"-ish

My goal is to have 200+ request per second, and i need to pass the list values for each thread at a time.

Is this possible to do with JmeterLib and Robot Framework?

```
*** Settings ***
Library           JMeterLib
Library           csvLibrary.py
*** Variables ***
${JMeter2_path}    C:/Users/User/Desktop/tools/apache-jmeter*/bin/jmeter.bat
${JMeter_script_1thread1loop_path}    Test Plan.jmx
${JMeter_log01_path}    results/jmeterTest1Thread1Loop_log01.jtl


*** Test Cases ***
Sort CSV Staff location file
    ${staff_ID_list}=  create list
    ${DeviceName_list}=  create list
    ${ExternalID_list}=  create list
    ${row_ID}=  convert to integer  1

    :FOR  ${Row_Elements}  IN RANGE  ${row_ID}  517
    \  ${read_csv} =  read cell value by row  staff.csv  ${row_ID}
    \  log  ${read_csv}
    \  ${Staff_ID}  get from dictionary   ${read_csv}  Col1
    \  append to list  ${staff_ID_list}  '${Staff_ID}'
    \  ${External_ID}  get from dictionary   ${read_csv}  Col2
    \  append to list  ${ExternalID_list}  '${External_ID}'
    \  ${DeviceName}  get from dictionary   ${read_csv}  Col3
    \  append to list  ${DeviceName_list}  '${DeviceName}'
    \  ${row_ID}=  evaluate  ${row_ID} + 1
    log  ${staff_ID_list}
    log  ${ExternalID_list}
    log  ${DeviceName_list}

jmeter2_tc1_justRunJMeter
    run jmeter    ${JMeter2_path}    ${JMeter_script_1thread1loop_path}    ${JMeter_log01_path}
```

And this is my test plan to hit stackoverflow 200 times per second.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.0 r1840935">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">2</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">200</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">0.1</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree/>
      <ConfigTestElement guiclass="HttpDefaultsGui" testclass="ConfigTestElement" testname="HTTP Request Defaults" enabled="true">
        <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
          <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">stackoverflow.com</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.concurrentPool">6</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
      </ConfigTestElement>
      <hashTree/>
      <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
        <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
        <objProp>
          <name>saveConfig</name>
          <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
            <time>true</time>
            <latency>true</latency>
            <timestamp>true</timestamp>
            <success>true</success>
            <label>true</label>
            <code>true</code>
            <message>true</message>
            <threadName>true</threadName>
            <dataType>true</dataType>
            <encoding>false</encoding>
            <assertions>true</assertions>
            <subresults>true</subresults>
            <responseData>false</responseData>
            <samplerData>false</samplerData>
            <xml>false</xml>
            <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
            <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
            <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
            <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
            <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
            <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
            <bytes>true</bytes>
            <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
            <url>true</url>
            <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
            <idleTime>true</idleTime>
            <connectTime>true</connectTime>
          </value>
        </objProp>
        <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
      </ResultCollector>
      <hashTree/>
      <ResultCollector guiclass="SummaryReport" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="Summary Report" enabled="true">
        <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
        <objProp>
          <name>saveConfig</name>
          <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
            <time>true</time>
            <latency>true</latency>
            <timestamp>true</timestamp>
            <success>true</success>
            <label>true</label>
            <code>true</code>
            <message>true</message>
            <threadName>true</threadName>
            <dataType>true</dataType>
            <encoding>false</encoding>
            <assertions>true</assertions>
            <subresults>true</subresults>
            <responseData>false</responseData>
            <samplerData>false</samplerData>
            <xml>false</xml>
            <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
            <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
            <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
            <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
            <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
            <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
            <bytes>true</bytes>
            <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
            <url>true</url>
            <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
            <idleTime>true</idleTime>
            <connectTime>true</connectTime>
          </value>
        </objProp>
        <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
      </ResultCollector>
      <hashTree/>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
```

***My Question:***  is there a way to pass the in the parameters dynamically to the test plan upon execution with robot framework?

Comment: Did you mean you want to set Dynamic parameter in Jmeter by using robotframework ? if so which parameter tha't dynamic ?

Comment: @SidaraKEO yes for example something like `run jmeter with parameters  ${staff_ID_list}   ${JMeter2_path}    ${JMeter_script_1thread1loop_path}    ${JMeter_log01_path}`

Comment: my sugesstion in your case , can you use loop in jmeter to loop data from your CSV . i think no need robotframework to loop it